# How to dynamically assign the class by page name using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET I want to create a common navigation bar. I face a problem while assigning the "Active" class on the list. I have come up with this code so far, but it is not working as expected.

**ASP.NET Code**

```
<li class='<% CurrentOrNot("Dashboard"); %>'><a href="Dashboard.aspx"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
<li class="<% CurrentOrNot("graphs"); %>"> <a href="charts.html"><i class="icon icon-signal"></i> <span>Charts &amp; graphs</span></a> </li>
<li class="<% CurrentOrNot("widgets"); %>"> <a href="widgets.aspx"><i class="icon icon-inbox"></i> <span>Widgets</span></a> </li>
<li class="<% CurrentOrNot("tables"); %>"><a href="tables.html"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> <span>Tables</span></a></li>
<li class="<% CurrentOrNot("full"); %>"><a href="grid.html"><i class="icon icon-fullscreen"></i> <span>Full width</span></a></li>
```

**My C# Code**

```
public string CurrentOrNot(string navItem)
{
    String originalPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;
    String parentDirectory = originalPath.Substring(0, originalPath.LastIndexOf("/"));

    string file=Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

    if(file.Contains(navItem))
    {
        return "Active";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly, the server side code sends the "Active" string depending on the condition, but the name is not assigned to the class attribute.

Comment: <%=CurrentOrNot("Dashboard"); %>'

Comment: @LaurentLequenne It is not working it say " ) expected"

Comment: you forgort the '=' and you should remove the ;